# Where is the location of MUnit in Wolfram Workbench 2.0 for the Mac?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have Mathematica 8.0 and Wolfram Workbench 2.0 for the Mac.  I want to use MUnit to unit test a package I am creating, but I am finding the lack of documentation on MUnit to be frustrating.

The best resource so for has been [Mathematic Cookbook by Sal Mangano](http://books.google.com/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Section 19.11 covers "Integrating Wolfram Workbench’s MUnit Package into the Frontend".

I figure once I expose MUnit to the frontend, I will be able to query the MUnit API with ? .  Just one problem, I can't find the MUnit package.  I tried to locate the MUnit directory as suggested in the book with:

```
find / -name MUnit -print 2> /dev/null
```

, but have not had any luck.

Comment: The call to `find` works, only after the MUnit package has been used in Wolfram Workbench. See Szabolcs comment to the accepted answer. **Please show Szabolcs some luv by up voting his comment to the accepted answer and his answer.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***If you up vote this answer, please show Szabolcs some luv by up voting his answer too. He was a tremendous help on this.***

The location of MUnit is dependent upon the order that features of Wolfram Workbench were first used. *That is just a theory, however it explains why `find` was not able to find MUnit initially, but finds it now.* On my system MUnit is located at:

```
/Applications/Wolfram\ Workbench.app/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/214/1/.cp/MathematicaSourceVersioned/Head/MUnit
```

**To locate MUnit on your system using Wolfram Workbench:**

1. Create a test case that calls your code.
2. Place a break point in your code that is tested by the test case.
3. Debug the test case.
4. Once you stop at the break point, keep stepping into the code and eventually you will step into Test.m when you step into `TestID->"MyTest-20111230-L0X3S3"`.
5. Hover the mouse over the Tab for Test.m and you will see the location of Test.m.

[image: location to Test.m in Mac version]

**To locate MUnit on your system using `find`:**

1. Create a test case in Wolfram Workbench.
2. Open terminal and type: `find / -name MUnit -print 2> /dev/null`

`find` results:

```
/Applications/Wolfram Workbench.app/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/214/1/.cp/MathematicaSourceVersioned/Head/MUnit
/Applications/Wolfram Workbench.app/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/214/1/.cp/MathematicaSourceVersioned/Version5.2/MUnit
/Applications/Wolfram Workbench.app/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/214/1/.cp/MathematicaSourceVersioned/Version6/MUnit
```

**Once you find the location you can query the MUnit package with:** *(note: the path most likely be slightly different)*

```
AppendTo[$Path, 
  FileNameJoin[{"/", "Applications", "Wolfram Workbench.app", 
    "configuration", "org.eclipse.osgi", "bundles", "214", "1", ".cp",
     "MathematicaSourceVersioned", "Head", "MUnit"}]];
Needs["MUnit`"];
?MUnit`*
(* Need a blank line after ?MUnit`* otherwise a nasty message is generated. *)
```

Comment: I took another look at it with a clearer head today, and it appears that these files aren't even extracted before you use the functionality from Workbench itself. Furthermore, the path is not the same everywhere.  To make this answer useful to everyone, can you please explain in detail how you found the path?

Answer (score 5):

I found `MUnit.m` in

```
...\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\347\1\.cp\MathematicaSourceVersioned\Head\MUnit
```

within the Eclipse (or Workbench) installation directory.  I don't have a Mac, but it should be in the same place regardless of platform.

There are also two other versions for Mathematica 6 and 5.2 (replace `Head` in the path with `Version5.2` or `Version6`).

Comment: Unfortunately not on a Mac. `ls /Applications/Wolfram\ Workbench.app/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles 
100 124 132 147 158 171 176 180 207 211 215 42 69 96
112 125 133 154 161 172 177 187 209 213 216 54 84
123 126 135 157 163 175 179 188 210 214 29 66 91`

Comment: @mmorris Well, you can always get the Eclipse version (platform independent) and extract it from there.  That's where I checked.  I don't know what those numbers mean, maybe yours is in a differently numbered directory?

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the solutions presented by @Szabolcs and @mmorris, here is another way to determine the location of `MUnit.m`.

In the Wolfram Workbench, create an MUnit test that looks like this:

```
Test[
  FindFile @ FileNameJoin @ {"MUnit", "MUnit.m"}
, ""
, TestID -> "FindMUnit-20120103-W7S3Q4"
]
```

Run the test.  It will fail, but the actual output of the test will be the desired pathname.

[image: screenshot showing failed unit test with the desired pathname]