# Looking for something like JUnit's @Before / @After in MUnit

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am writting a number of test cases in a single .mt file that share common setup (and teardown) procedure(s).  I was hoping to see something like JUnit's `@Before` / `@After`, but nothing from the MUnit package jumped out at me that that would accomplish this.  In all honesty, the MUnit package documentation is a little better than the Wolfram Workbench's MUnit documentation, but it too is far from complete.  [Instructions on viewing the MUnit package.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684052/where-is-the-location-of-munit-in-wolfram-workbench-2-0-for-the-mac)

So before I go reinventing the wheel, I thought I would check to see if I missed something in MUnit or if anyone has a pattern that works well?

So based on Leonid Shifrin ***initial*** answer (he updated his answer while I put this together) this is (was) where I am (was) at ...

**TestPlus.mt**

```
(* Mathematica Test File *)

(* x is a global value *)
x=0;

SetUp[] := Module[{}, x=1;];
TearDown[] := Module[{}, x=0;];

(* test SetUp[] *)
SetUp[];       
Test[x, 1, TestID->"SetUp-20120103-F2U9V6"]

(* test TearDown[] *)
TearDown[];
Test[x, 0, TestID->"TearDown-20120103-O4R6M7"]

(* test plus --contrived tests-- *)
SetUp[];
Test[x+0, 1, TestID->"Plus-20120103-S5D9X6"]
TearDown[];

SetUp[];
Test[x+1, 2, TestID->"Plus-20120103-D7Q3E0"]
TearDown[];

SetUp[];
Test[x+2, 3, TestID->"Plus-20120103-F0S4P9"]
TearDown[];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MUnit` files are normal package files, and they are read and executed sequentially - or at least this has been my experience with them. You can simply add lines with your common code before and after your tests, and they will be executed before and after all the tests respectively.

If you want to invoke your setup and  teardown procedures individually for each test, you can add the corresponding lines (calls) just before and just after each test. You may find it convenient then to write a preprocessor, which would load your tests as a package (for example, by using `Import["Tests.tm","HeldExpressions"]` - where your tests are in `Tests.tm` in this example), and inserting the corresponding lines and then saving a file again. This will require some fluency with manipulations with held code, but can be picked up reasonably quickly, and is very convenient if you have many tests.

**EDIT**

As a more light-weight alternative, you can define  macro-like short-cuts. Here is an example test file contents:

```
(* Mathematica Test File *)

before[]:= (Print["Before Test: ",f[2]];f[x_]:=x^3);
after[] := (ClearAll[f];Print["After Test: ",f[2]]);

SetAttributes[withCodeAfter,HoldRest];
withCodeAfter[before_,after_]:=(after;before)

SetAttributes[{wrapTest,wrapTest1},HoldAll]
wrapTest[code_]:= withCodeAfter[before[];code,after[]]  
wrapTest1[code_]:=Block[{f},f[x_]:=x^3;code];

wrapTest@
Test[f[2],
  8,
  TestID -> "MyTest1"
]

wrapTest1@
Test[f[2],
  8,
  TestID -> "MyTest2"
]
```

The functions `before` and `after` imitate your setup / teardown functions. The function `withCodeAfter` is a helper macro which executes code `before` first, then executes code `after`, but as a result returns the result of `before`. The functions `wrapTest` and `wrapTest1` illustrate two possibilities: you can either define separate "before" and "after" functions and sandwich your code with them, or you can use `Block` and define the "around" macro, which may be sometimes more convenient. Tests will work either way. You can also mix these approaches. In both cases, the amount of boilerplate code is minimal - just add `wrapTest@` line before each test.

Comment: Okay I updated my question with an lame example of what I thought you were talking about. Now, I see what you are talking about. Thanks

Comment: @mmorris Thanks for the accept. Your update is indeed what I meant in my initial answer. My update was just to show how you can reduce the amount of boilerplate code with relatively minimal effort.

Comment: Please see the answer below.  Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the formatting correct in the comment so I am doing this as an answer...

Okay I think I have the dissected the code in your answer, please let me know if I am correct.

---

Defines what is evaluated before and after the "test case" is evaluated.  A side note, you are defining `f` in `before`, undefining `f` in `after`.

```
(* Mathematica Test File *)

before[]:= (Print["Before Test: ",f[2]];f[x_]:=x^3);
after[] := (ClearAll[f];Print["After Test: ",f[2]]);
```

---

Defines the function `withCodeAfter`. It takes two expressions, the first expression, `before`, is evaluated when passed in.  The second expression, `after`, is passed in unevaluated and is the first expression to be evaluated within `withCodeAfter`.  The evaluated first expression, `before`, is returned by `withCodeAfter`.

```
SetAttributes[withCodeAfter,HoldRest];
withCodeAfter[before_,after_]:=(after;before)
```

---

Defines the function `wrapTest`. It takes one expression, `code`, that is passed in unevaluated.  That expression, `code`, is the second expression of a compound expression, `before[];code`, that is passed as the first expression, `before`, to `withCodeAfter`.  The compound expression, `before[];code`, is evaluated when passed into `withCodeAfter`.  The value of the evaluated expression, `code`, is returned by `withCodeAfter` following `after` being evaluated.  The value returned by `withCodeAfter` is returned by `wrapTest`.

```
SetAttributes[{wrapTest},HoldAll]
wrapTest[code_]:= withCodeAfter[before[];code,after[]]
```

---

Is the same thing as calling `wrapTest[Test[f[2], 8, TestID -> "MyTest1"]]`

```
wrapTest@
Test[f[2], 8, TestID -> "MyTest1"]
```

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct - this is exactly what is happening.  The function `withCodeAfter` is just a convenience function, it is not essential - just saves an introduction of auxiliary variable to hold the result of `before`. It is actually a macro, and perhaps the smallers of the useful macros I know. Sorry if my answer wasn't very clear.